# How can I make pip uninstall packages that are no longer required by other packages?

Tags: python, pip

For example, I may have installed `pkg1`, which requires `pkg2` and `pkg3`. No other packages I have installed require these two. So, during or after `pip uninstall pkg1`, how can I make pip uninstall `pkg2` and `pkg3`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy builtin command or flag in pip to do this, but before uninstalling pkg1, you can determine the dependencies:

```
$ pip show pkg1 | grep Requires
```

You can quickly get a summary of package requirements with a little bash fu:

```
$ for P in $(pip list | awk '{print $1}') ; do echo -n $P::' '; pip show $P | grep Requires ; done
```

Then for any of the packages the first command shows (pkg2 and pkg3), if they aren't shown as dependencies for any other packages in the second command, you can explicitly `pip uninstall` those as well.

You can also find all of the packages that aren't dependencies of any other package:

```
$ cat <(pip show $(pip list | awk '{print $1}') | grep Requires | sed -e s/Requires:// -e s/,//g | xargs -n 1) <(pip list | awk '{print $1}') | sort | uniq -u
```

Comment: Good question.  Looks like it was added in version 1.3 of pip.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pip can do this.

If you are in virtualenv you just delete it and reinstall into new one.

If you are in system, you should never use pip but the distribution package manager.

Comment: I think it's a little strong to say "you should _never_ use pip".

Comment: Especially when it will be included in [newer versions of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453/).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do this manually as pip will not know what other packages depend on `pkg2` and `pkg3`.

The best way to go about this is with a [virtual environment](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/); which allows you to isolate Python packages from your system (base) Python.